# Intel UHD Graphics is missing on my laptop

Tags: graphics-card, amd-radeon, hp-laptop

hope you can help me. i upgraded my HP laptop storage by adding SSD and was reformatted. as far as i remember, there are 2 graphics card, Intel UHD Graphics and Radeon Graphics before it was reformatted. Now, i check dxidiag.exe and saw Microsoft Basic Display Adapter on Display Tab and Radeon Graphics on Render Tab which is new to me. i am pretty sure it was Intel before on the Display Tab. is it possible to get it back and how? thank you!

[Display Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyBPI.png)

[Render Rab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSmEB.png)

Comment: Could you clarify "adding SSD and was reformatted"? Did you add an SSD as a secondary drive, or make the SSD your boot drive? What exactly was reformatted?

Comment: @TylerN yes i added SSD for boot drive then my laptop  was reformatted by the technician.

Comment: Installing drivers is a basic part of system set up. While more and more drivers are identified and loaded automatically by the OS you still need to check the device manager and identify, download, and install any missing drivers.

Answer (score 2):

> I upgraded my HP laptop storage by adding SSD and was reformatted.

So all of your drivers (except BIOS) need to be properly re-installed again.

Get the HP Driver Update Assistant App (HP Support Site), download it, install it and run it to identify drivers that need to be updated.

Complete the update, restart and test.

Comment: okay will try these and see what will happen next. thanks for the help. :D